# Multiple UILabels in UITAbleViewCell with dynamic height

Tags: uitableview, swift, dynamic, ios8, autolayout

In an empty `UITableViewCell` i have two `UILabel`s aligned like this: |--label1----label2--|. *Both* of them will be populated dynamically. I need to set the constraints in a way that both labels remain center-aligned but the *cell's height* be determined by the label that has the *most content*.
So far:

- Labels' number of lines are set to 0
- In `ViewDidLoad`:

  ```
  tableView.rowHeight = 40.0
  tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40.0
  ```
- `UITableViewDelegate` methods:

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
  }
  ```

  The problem is i cannot find the proper constraints setup to achieve a result like this:
  |---------------------------a longer message--|
  |--a long message-------a longer message--|
  |--a long message-------a longer message--|
  |--a long message-------a longer message--|
  |--a long message-------a longer message--|
  |---------------------------a longer message--|
  or

  |------------------------a longer message--|
  |--message------------a longer message--|
  |------------------------a longer message--|
  Any ideas? I'm using `Swift 1.2`, `Xcode 6.3` (and `Storyboard`)
  Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with the constraints and code I used.  I didn't need to adjust the horizontal compression or content hugging.  Hope that helps! :)  (Haven't learned Swift yet, sorry for the Objective-C!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Add a (lower priority) fixed height constraint for the cell (e.g. = 40).</s>

Add a top and bottom constraint for each label.  Make the top constraint a fixed margin (e.g. = 8).  Make the bottom constraint a (higher priority) greater than or equal constraint (e.g. >= 8).

The cell's height will be determined by the taller label, and all the other vertical constraints will still be met.

**Update:**

It turns out that you don't need a fixed height constraint for the cell, or even need to tweak the horizontal content hugging or compression resistance priorities.

I pinned the labels' top and left or right edge to the superview.margin, = 0, and added a horizontal space between the labels >= 4.

I pinned the labels' bottom edge to the superview.margin, >= 0.  I also set both labels' vertical compression resistance priority to 1000.

*At this point, we've set the minimum necessary constraints.  However, if both labels are long, one label will take most of the width, forcing the other label to be extremely narrow.  I arbitrarily added a width >= 100 constraint to both labels to balance things out.*

[image: Label constraints]

Enable self-sizing in `-viewDidLoad`, then assign your labels' text, and have the cell lay itself out.  It wasn't necessary to override anything in the custom `UITableViewCell`.

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     cell.leftLabel.text = ...;
     cell.rightLabel.text = ...;

     [cell setNeedsLayout];
     [cell layoutIfNeeded];

     return cell;
}
```

[image: Snapshot of tableView with dynamic side-by-side labels]

Comment: Being struggling these days but it seems that i'm missing something. Can you please explain to me in more details? Top and bottom constraints seems to be fine. The problem is in the horizontal ones.. It's like the constraint between the two labels is not working and the height is determined by one of them according to content hugging - compression resistance values, witch i don't quite understand the values i must set. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want the labels to have equal widths?

Comment: No, I just want them to be y - aligned (center, top it doesn't matter for now) side by side with a minimum (>= 4 for example) distance between them with the leftmost have a leading space and the rightmost have a trailing space.

Comment: Ok.  So, if one label needs more horizontal space than the other, Auto Layout needs to know if one label should give up space to the other.  That's the compression resistance priority.  Compression resistance says "This is the size I want to be.  I won't let you make me more narrow."

Comment: Thanks man! Now it's working fine! I was missing that width constraint.. Thanks again for your time!